# How to Appropriately Call Functions within Nested Functions

Tags: javascript, html

I have read a few different ways to call the functions but have had no luck in the code below. I believe that is my error as to why nothing displays when the button is clicked. How do I appropriately call the functions so the results display? This is for an assignment and I am currently stuck. Any clarification and explanation would greatly be appreciated.

```
<script>

        // function for button
        function calculateFormulas(){

            
            let height = document.getElementById("height").value;
            let width = document.getElementById("width").value;
            let area;
            let perimeter;
            let distance; 

            // function to calculate area
            function calculateArea(){

                let area = parseInt(height * width);
                console.log(area);

            }

            //function to calcuate perimeter
            function calculatePerimeter(){

                let perimeter = 2 * parseInt(height + width);
                console.log(perimeter);
            }
            //function to calculate distance
            function calculateDistance(){

                let distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(height, 2) + Math.pow(width, 2));
                console.log(distance);
            }

            //returns values to the "results" div
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "This area of the rectangle is " + area + " units squared, " + "the perimeter is " + perimeter +
             " units, and the distance between opposite corners is " + distance + " units.";
            

        }





    </script>
</head>
```

```
<body>
    <h1>Rectangle Calculator</h1>

    <p>This program will report information about a rectangle</p>

    <form id="myform" >

        <table>
            <tr>
            <td>Height</td>
                 <!--input field for height value --> 
            <td><input id="height" type="number" value=""> </td>   
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Width</td>
                <!--input field for width field --> 
            <td><input id="width"  type="number" value=""></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

            <input id="report"  type="button" value="Report Details" onclick="calculateFormulas()">

            <div id="results"></div>

        
    </form> 
    
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to call each function.
2. You should not declare a variable again inside functions.

For example,

```
  function calculateArea() {

    let area = parseInt(height * width);
    console.log(area);

  };
```

should be:

```js
  (function calculateArea() {

    area = parseInt(height * width);
    console.log(area);

  }());
```

```js
// function for button
function calculateFormulas() {


  let height = document.getElementById("height").value;
  let width = document.getElementById("width").value;
  let area;
  let perimeter;
  let distance;

  // function to calculate area
  (function calculateArea() {

    area = parseInt(height * width);
    console.log(area);

  }());

  //function to calcuate perimeter
  function calculatePerimeter() {

    let perimeter = 2 * parseInt(height + width);
    console.log(perimeter);
  }
  //function to calculate distance
  function calculateDistance() {

    let distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(height, 2) + Math.pow(width, 2));
    console.log(distance);
  }

  //returns values to the "results" div
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "This area of the rectangle is " + area + " units squared, " + "the perimeter is " + perimeter +
    " units, and the distance between opposite corners is " + distance + " units.";


}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Rectangle Calculator</h1>

  <p>This program will report information about a rectangle</p>

  <form id="myform">

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Height</td>
        <!--input field for height value -->
        <td><input id="height" type="number" value=""> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Width</td>
        <!--input field for width field -->
        <td><input id="width" type="number" value=""></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <input id="report" type="button" value="Report Details" onclick="calculateFormulas()">

    <div id="results"></div>


  </form>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the explanation and example. This helps me understand what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

u did not give proper instruction to the function on how it should react when it get something. also you should separate out the function and call them only when require.